# Can't run a Java GUI program coded w/ Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, user-interface, package, sublimetext3

I've tried the sublime text forums but got nothing there. I wrote a simple Java GUI program (sorry for my bad definition, I'm ignorant) which imports those packages:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.swing.*;
import java.swing.border.*;
```

But when I hit the CTRL + B combination to build and run the program, I get the following errors:

```
AddressBook.java:4: error: package java.swing does not exist
import java.swing.*;
^
AddressBook.java:5: error: package java.swing.border does not exist
import java.swing.border.*;
^
AddressBook.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public class AddressBook extends JFrame {
^
symbol: class JFrame
AddressBook.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
private JTextField jtfName = new JTextField(NAME_SIZE);
^
symbol: class JTextField
location: class AddressBook
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Swing is part of javax, not java.

Comment: As compass said, you got the wrong package. IMHO if you're starting with Java you should seriously consider switching to an IDE (Eclipse is both great and free) or some editor with code completion.

Comment: Yeah, @Compass is obviously right :) But I think it's gonna be more helpful me to be able to code in environments like Sublime. I was used to code in NetBeans but I thought I should be able to code in more simpler conditions, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct import statements would be:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
```

Notice "javax" vs "java".

This is why using a good IDE is very helpful.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. The last two packages should've started with "javax" not "java. But I think, the rest of them is ok.

Actually, I was coding in NetBeans but I though it'd be better to be able to code in much simpler environments.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: indeed, i have edited my answer, I blindly added "x" without paying attention if it was an actually a swing related import.

Answer (score 3):

You should `import javax.swing.*` rather than `java.swing.*`

Also, you don't need to then import `swing.border`, as `swing.*` will pull in all of the contents of the `swing` package.

But really, I would recommend you to download IntelliJ IDEA community edition to make your life much easier =)

Comment: Yeah, the last two packages should be "javax" not "java".

By the way, I have some lines like `jpAddress.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));` so deleting the `javax.swing.border.*;` line ends up with errors. So, they seem necessary.

Thanks for your interest!